# trouble creating makefiles

Tags: makefile, clang++

I always have a problem creating makefiles for some reason. In this case, I'm using clang++ with -std=c++11.
I have an executable Carbuyer.cpp that depends on a CarFactory (.cpp and .h) which in turn relies on Car(.cpp and .h)

my Current attempt looks like this:

```
CarBuyer: CarBuyer.cpp CarFactory Car
    clang++ -std=c++11 -v -o CarBuyer CarBuyer.cpp CarFactory Car
Car: Car.cpp Car.h
    clang++ -std=c++11 Car.cpp Car.h
CarFactory: CarFactory.cpp CarFactory.h
    clang++ -std=c++11 CarFactory CarFactory.cpp CarFactory.h 
clean:
    rm -f core CarBuyer
```

But i'm getting an undefined function error originating from CarFactory when compiling:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 CarFactory.cpp CarFactory.h 
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode,
     this behavior is deprecated
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In
    function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/CarFactory-13dbb4.o: In function `FordFactory::makeCar()':
CarFactory.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `Ford::Ford()'
/tmp/CarFactory-13dbb4.o: In function `ToyotaFactory::makeCar()':
CarFactory.cpp:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `Toyota::Toyota()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [CarFactory] Error 1
```

The code compiles fine in VS2015 but not when compiling with clang++, leading me to believe my error is in the Makefile.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to tell compiler to compile with `-c` option.

Second, output files must be defined: with `-o file` or better `-o $@`

```
CarBuyer: CarBuyer.o CarFactory.o Car.o
    clang++ -std=c++11 -o $@ CarBuyer.o CarFactory.o Car.o

CarBuyer.o: CarBuyer.cpp
    clang++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ CarBuyer.cpp

Car.o: Car.cpp Car.h
    clang++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ Car.cpp Car.h

CarFactory.o: CarFactory.cpp CarFactory.h
    clang++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ CarFactory.cpp CarFactory.h 

clean:
    rm -f core CarBuyer *.o
```

Having header file into compile rules is quite unusual, give it a check and suppress them from clang++ command lines if you can.